# How to interpret smoothing effects in the summary output of a generalised additive mixed effect model GAMM

Tags: r, modeling

I have been using GAMMs to analyse time series data and I have included a smoothing term (hour of day by season) and I cant seem to find the results for the winter season. I have the proper information (edf, Ref.df, F, and p value) for all my smoothed terms and each season except for winter. I am using the summary function and calling on the gam results within the model (instead of the lme summary output).

Attached is a snapshot of the summary output. Hopefully I am just missing something simple.

[image: summary output]